# MSSQL module converting return value to int?

Tags: node.js

We are using the MSSQL module with Node.js.

I am running the following query:

```
    SELECT AVG((RAT_VALUE * 1.0)) FROM RAT WHERE RAT_PER_ID_FROM IS NOT NULL AND RAT_PER_ID_ABOUT = 139 AND RAT_USE = 'Y' AND RAT_ABOUT_ROLE = 'RS' AND RAT_DATE_INSERTED >= '10/1/2018' AND RAT_DATE_INSERTED < '10/1/2019'
```

If I run this against the database directly, it returns:

4.45

The output from MSSQL is:

4
The exact resultset returned is:

```
results { recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
  recordset: [ { '': 4 } ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 1 ] }
```

In other words, MSSQL is always returning the value 4, instead of 4.45.

The column type od RAT_VALUE is INT in the database but I've tried changing it to DECIMAL(5, 2) without any luck.

I've tried explicitly returning a DECIMAL from the query like:

```
    SELECT CAST(AVG((RAT_VALUE * 1.0)) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) ...
```

But no luck there either.

It seems MSSQL is simply clipping and dropping the decimal part of any number, even numbers of Decimal types.

I even set the value as 4.75 in the database and returned it directly and it still returns 4.

Any ideas out there?